# Namespace for Keyword "Populate" C# (MvcMailer)

Tags: c#

I've converted my project from .Net framework 4 to 4.5.

I have done this to make use of the Nuget package MvcMailer.

All is good except in the UserMailer class the following code exists:

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage Welcome()
{
        //ViewBag.Data = someObject;
        return Populate(x =>
        {
            x.Subject = "Welcome";
            x.ViewName = "Welcome";
            x.To.Add("some-email@example.com");
        });
}
```

The Populate word throws an error:
The name 'Populate' does not exist in the current context

To what Namespace does the word Populate belong to?
Or is it an extension?

I can't find anything on the net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a class method of `MailerBase` controller with this signature ([from source code on GitHub](https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/blob/master/Mvc.Mailer/MailerBase.cs)):

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage Populate(Action<MvcMailMessage> action)
```

To use it you must derive your controller from `MailerBase` (*it's the base class for Mailers. Your mailer should subclass `MailerBase`*).

For example, supposing your controller is named `Home`, from:

```
public class Home : Controller {
```

To:

```
public class Home : MailerBase {
```

It's in `Mvc.Mailer` namespace (same of `MvcMailerMessage` class) anyway it's not an extension method so you don't even need to worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the cursor on the keyword and hit `Alt+Shift+F10`. It will show you it's source, and you'll be able to include the whole namespace, or use the keyword just once. It will only work if you have a correct .dll reference in your project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got the code from this GitHub repository.

https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/wiki/MvcMailer-Step-by-Step-Guide

```
public virtual MvcMailMessage Welcome()
{
    ViewBag.Name = "Sohan";
    return Populate(x =>{
          x.viewName = "Welcome";
          x.To.Add("sohan39@example.com");
        });
}
```

This code was provided by the Developer of the Package and he showed how to use it to edit the MvcMailer.

If so, the guy there used these namespaces in the top of his C# file.

```
using Mvc.Mailer;
```

So, I guess it would be a part of this Namespace. Include it to your project and you're done!

Comment: Not really. It's a controller method and it's invoking that from within controller (=method not found). You don't need to include namespace (anyway it's included because he's using MvcMailMessage class as result). Problem he is deriving from wrong controller.